# Se crashea con "process returned 255(0xff)"

Tags: c

El programa me deja meter el número de notas que quiero y las notas que son, pero luego cuando tiene que escribir el array de vuelta, se me crashea con un `"process returned 255(0xff)"`.

El codigo :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define notas 50

main(){
    int N;
    float A[notas];
    printf("Cuantas notas quieres poner? ");
    scanf("%i",&N);
    leernotas(A,N);
    copiarNotas(N,A);
    escribirNotas(N,A);
}

void leernotas(float A[], int N){
    int I=0;
    while(N>I){
        I=I+1;
        printf("Escribe la nota numero %i :",I);
        scanf("%f",&A[I]);
    }
}

void copiarNotas(float destino[], float origen[], int N) {
    int I=0;
    while(N>I){
        destino[I] = origen[I];
        I=I+1;
    }
}

void escribirNotas(float A[], int N) {
    int I=0;
    while(I<N){
        printf("Nota numero %i : %f ",I, A[I]);
        I=I+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: El código que muestras no llega a fallar, el código que muestras no llega a compilarse.

Comment: La función `copiarNotas`, por ejemplo, tiene 3 argumentos y la llamada solo tiene 2 ... ese código necesita algún que otro repaso para que se reproduzca el error que comentas

Comment: las funciones void deverias declararlas encima de main tambien. Solo declararlas, es decir escrive encima de main todos los void. Ejemplo: void leernotas(float A[ ], int N);

Comment: Considera seguir las convenciones de nombrado de variables, como escribir los identificadores de variables en minúscula, separando las palabras por guión bajo, o mejor, utilizando lower camel case. Dicho esto, te falta definir completamente la función main, pues la forma que has puesto no es estándar. Más información en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158541/main-function-defined-without-return-type-gives-warning), y en [este artículo](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2014/02/c-standard-quibbles.html).

Answer (score 0):

Al compilar tu código, obtenemos *algún que otro* aviso:

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o test test.c
```

> warning: return type defaults to `int`
> warning: implicit declaration of function `leernotas`
> warning: implicit declaration of function `copiarNotas`
> warning: implicit declaration of function `escribirNotas`
> warning: conflicting types for `leernotas` note: previous implicit declaration of ‘leernotas’ ... 
> warning: conflicting types for ‘copiarNotas’ note: previous implicit declaration of `copiarNotas` ...
> warning: conflicting types for `escribirNotas` note: previous implicit declaration of...

Esto es así porque el lenguaje C es **extremadamente permisivo** y *hará lo que pueda* ... pero ya nos está avisando de que los resultados que obtendremos **pueden no ser los esperados**.

Centremonos en tu problema principal:

```
main( ){
    int N;
    float A[notas];
    ...
    leernotas( A, N );
    copiarNotas( N, A );
    escribirNotas( N, A );
}
```

Y, si miramos el código de tu función `copiarNotas( destino, origen, N )`, vemos que su misión es copiar elementos desde la posición en memoria `origen` hacia la posición en memoria `destino`.

Sin embargo, la llamas usando tu variable `N` como destino ... la cual fué introducida por el usuario, y es un entero (`int`).

Ya dijimos que el lenguaje hará lo que pueda: interpretará ese entero como si fuera un puntero, e intentará realizar la copia.

Si el usuario introdujo, por ejemplo, el número `3`, se estará intentando copiar datos **hacia la posición en memoria `0x00000003`**. Lo cual **puede** funcionar en algunos sistemas ... pero no es el caso de un PC moderno.

En los PC actuales, existen zonas de memoria **protegidas** por el Sistema Operativo para diversos fines. Y, normalmente, todas las direcciones de memoria pertenecientes a la página `0` están protegidas: desde la `0x0` hasta la `0x1000`.

Volviendo al problema: **no tienes prevista una zona de memoria *destino* para esa copia**.

Basta con que la obtengas de alguna forma ... por ejemplo, con una variable adicional:

```
main( ) {
    int N;
    float A[notas];
    float B[notas]; /* <--- AQUÍ +/
    printf( "Cuantas notas quieres poner ? " );
    scanf( "%i", &N );
    leernotas( A, N ); /* Cambio. */
    copiarNotas( B, A, N ); /* Cambio. */
    escribirNotas( B, N ); /* Cambio. */
}
```

Obviamente, también será imprescindible modificar los argumentos que pasas a las demás funciones implicadas.